# How to insert a NULL value in PL/SQL Procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

For example table Foobars,

```
CREATE TABLE Foobars(
   foo NUMBER,
   bar NUMBER
);
```

How to **insert** a **NULL** value from a **variable** in **dynamic** PL/SQL procedure?

```
DECLARE
   var_foo  NUMBER := 69;
   var_bar  NUMBER := NULL;
   l_insert_statement VARCHAR2(128);
BEGIN
   -- Assembles insert statement
   l_insert_statement :=
      'INSERT INTO Foobars VALUES (' ||
         var_foo || ', ' ||
         var_bar ||
      ');';
   -- Executes insert statement
   EXECUTE immediate (l_insert_statement);
END;
/
```

The query returns ORA-00936 at the "EXECUTE immediate..." line: **missing expression**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass variables in dynamic SQL using string concatenation, pass them as bind variables (and remove the `;` statement terminator in the dynamic SQL string):

```sql
DECLARE
   var_foo  NUMBER := 69;
   var_bar  NUMBER := NULL;
   l_insert_statement VARCHAR2(128);
BEGIN
   -- Assembles insert statement
   l_insert_statement := 'INSERT INTO Foobars VALUES (:1, :2)';
   -- Executes insert statement
   EXECUTE immediate l_insert_statement USING var_foo, var_bar;
END;
/
```

Or, in this case, you don't need dynamic SQL:

```sql
DECLARE
   var_foo  NUMBER := 69;
   var_bar  NUMBER := NULL;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Foobars VALUES (var_foo, var_bar);
END;
/
```

And don't need PL/SQL and can just use a simple SQL statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO Foobars VALUES (69, NULL);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=178becfed487015e97a97ec28b423d7f)*

Answer (score 2):

Problem is terminating semi-colon in `l_insert_statement`; remove it

```
No : ');';
Yes: ')';
```

---

However, there's nothing dynamic in code you use so I'd suggest you to use simply

```
begin
  insert into foobars values (var_foo, var_bar);
end;
```